# Duplication of the recording when using view and left joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I have 5  table with parent children relationship

- UserInfo
- UserInformation
- UserEntryEntry
- Userinformation
- UserBusket

in parent children relationship i mean (userInfo's  recordId is primary key in UserInfo and foreign key in UserInformation and UserEntryEntry and in below tables the same relationship is maintained)
i have to make one view in which i should REUNION all this five table's record data.
the main problem is:

1.IN UserInformation  i have duplicated data, i guess  that't because it has records  about user's pre registration,registration and edit information and they don't have any different value except date , in my code below i tried to use max(datetime) but it doesn't seem to work, w**hat should i do to somehow 
resolve this duplication problem?**

2. The view somehow duplicates view , and i can't find out,what's the reason for this action. ( i ought to have 15 record while count on view shows me 15 record)

here  on the  picture are my table's raw  data  exmaple and  desired  result as well:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK19h.png)

CREATE VIEW UserRecords
AS
SELECT DISTINCT

```
                ,ISNULL(DeclInf.ID,'') AS  Guid
                ,ISNULL(DeclInf.UserNumber,'') AS UserNumber
                ,ISNULL(DeclInf.UserType,'')  AS UserType
                ,ISNULL(DeclInf.CustomerId,'') AS CustomerID
                ,'' AS CustomerName
                ,CONVERT(DATETIME,(SELECT MAX(ISNULL(Record.DocumentDate,'')) FROM [UserInformation] Document WITH (NOLOCK)
                    WHERE Document.DeclarationInformationGUID = DeclInf.DeclarationInformationGUID 
                    GROUP BY Document. ID),104) AS registrationDate

                ,ISNULL([Entry].TypeOfProduct,'') AS ModeOfProduct

                ,SUM(ProductWeigtCalculate.Weight) AS TotalDeclarationValue

                ,SUM(ProductTaxCalculate. Payments) AS TotalPayments
            FROM [UserInfo] Incoming WITH (NOLOCK)
            LEFT JOIN [UserInformation] DeclInf WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON DeclInf.IncomingGUID = Incoming.IncomingGUID 
            LEFT JOIN [UserEntryEntry] [Entry] WITH (NOLOCK)
            ON [Entry].DeclarationInformationGUID = DeclInf.DeclarationInformationGUID
            LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT DeclInf. GUID AS InformationGUID
                                            ,(ISNULL(UserBusket.Amount,0) + (DeclInf.CounterveilingDuty * (ISNULL(UserBusket.StatisticalValue,0) / ISNULL(NULLIF(UserBusket.SumStatisticalValue,0),1)))) AS ProductWeigtCalculate
                FROM [UserInformation] DeclInf WITH (NOLOCK)
                LEFT JOIN [UserEntryEntry] [Entry] WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON [Entry]. InformationGUID = DeclInf. InformationGUID AND 
                LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT DeclarationInformationGUID, SUM(StatisticalValue) AS SumStatisticalValue
                    FROM [UserEntryEntry] 
                    GROUP BY  InformationGUID, PartnerID) EntrySum
                    ON EntrySum. InformationGUID = DeclInf. InformationGUID 

            LEFT JOIN(
                SELECT DeclInf. InformationGUID AS InformationGUID
                                            ,(ISNULL(Tax10.Amount,0) + (DeclInf. Duty * (ISNULL([Entry].StatisticalValue,0) / ISNULL(NULLIF(EntrySum.SumStatisticalValue,0),1))) 
                      + ISNULL(Tax.Amount,0) + ISNULL(Tax.Amount,0) + ISNULL(Tax.Amount,0)
                      + ISNULL([Entry].LocalPortExpenses,0) + ISNULL([Entry].OtherLocalExpenses,0)
                      + ISNULL([Entry].FreightAmount,0) + ISNULL([Entry].InsuranceAmount,0)
                      + ISNULL([Entry].TresspassingFeeAtTheBorder,0)) AS Payments
                FROM [UserInformation] DeclInf WITH (NOLOCK)
                LEFT JOIN [UserEntryEntry] [Entry] WITH (NOLOCK)
                ON [Entry]. InformationGUID = DeclInf. InformationGUID                  
            GROUP BY DeclInf.DeclarationInformationGUID
                ,DeclInf.InformationGUID
                ,DeclInf.Tax
```

Answer (score 0):

based on the explanation on [UserInformation] table seems there are multiple types of transactions stored as rows for pre-registration,registration and edit information.

I am not sure about the dataset you have, but assume that there is atleast one record for each user in [UserInformation], if so we could change it to a INNER JOIN rather a LEFT OUTER.

Depending on the output you want from the users from who has pre-registration,registration and edit information, you have to do another join filter condition like

```
,SUM(ProductTaxCalculate. Payments) AS TotalPayments
        FROM [UserInfo] Incoming WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN [UserInformation] DeclInf WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON DeclInf.IncomingGUID = Incoming.IncomingGUID 
        AND transactiontype ='pre-registration'
```

AND transactiontype ='pre-registration' is something i think you should have to identify as a different column.

Comment: Thank  you for your answer, ins this case i need to sum up unique values based on latest  (registraiton or edit  it  data, i should choose edit if it is latest 
 for example ) i don't have to choose other  data anyway, i need to get  information based on latest record

Comment: In this case you have to group the values and you have to look for both transaction types and sum the values. but without some sample data and the expected output its hard to explain or give some code. please attache some sample data and expected output

Comment: Ok, i will redisign question and add this data also